# Showing that $Z_p[\alpha]$ has $p^2$ elements if $\alpha$ is a root

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to show that $Z_p[\alpha]$ has $p^2$ elements if $\alpha$ is a root. But I'm not sure I understand how this could be possible since $Z_p$ itself has only $p$ elements.

Is there a sense in which it is possible to show this, or am I right in that the question as stated is nonsense?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of what?

Comment: I took it to mean if $\alpha$ is a root of some polynomial in $Z_p[x]$; however, in context it is possible that the person who asked this question to me (which inspired me to write this post) meant for it to be the root of some $2nd$-degree polynomial in Z_p[x] s.t. $p > 2$.

Comment: What do you mean the person who asked the question? You are the person who asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $\alpha$ is a square root of some element since that is the only way that your question makes sense to me, also I assume that $p$ is a prime number. I also assume that $\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]$ is a ring that is obtained by adding $\alpha$ to it.

So, we know that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, therefore it makes sense to talk about Euclidean division in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$. So you need to identify $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(\alpha)=0$ and $\deg(p(x))=2$.

If $f(x) + (p(x)) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ then you can divide $f(x)$ by $p(x)$ and get $f(x)=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $\deg(r(x))<\deg(p(x))$.

But $p(x)q(x) \in (p(x))$ so we can say

$f(x) - r(x) = p(x)q(x) \in (p(x)) \implies f(x)+(p(x))=r(x)+(p(x))$

That means everything in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(p(x))$ can be identified by a polynomial of degree less than $2$. How may polynomials of degree less than $2$ you can have in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$? All such polynomials will be of the form $ax+b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. A simple counting argument shows that you'll have $p^2$ because you have $p$ choices for $a$ and $p$ choices for $b$ and that answers your question.

Comment: It's somewhat infelicitous to use $p$ both as the modulus and the (irreducible quadratic) polynomial (of which $\alpha$ is the root).

Comment: What is meant by $(p(x))$?

Comment: @user1770201: The ideal generated by $p(x)$ and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let me try to interpret your question. Are you asking whether for any polynomial $f$, $Z_p[x]/(f(x))=Z_p[\alpha]$ is the finite field with $p^2$ elements?

In general, that is not correct. For instance, adjoining a root of $x^3+x+1$ to $Z_2$ will actually give you the finite field with $8$ elements since this polynomial is irreducible in $Z_2[x]$.

In general, there exist irreducible degree $k$ polynomials and these will generate the finite field with $p^k$ elements.